# Не загружается JavaScript , после AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

у меня  есть таблица подгружающееся через AJAX и скрипт ее сортировки , но скрипт не выполняется после обновления страницы по AJAX. Как это исправить.
Вывод таблицы:

```
<table class="table" align="center">


<thead>
<tr>
    <th>  Id </th>
    <th >Тема собщения</th>
    <th>Дата</th>
    <th >Статус</th>
    <th>Подробно</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    {% for log in logs %}

        <tr>
            <td>{{ log.id }}</td>
            <td>
                {{ log.mailSubject }}

                {% if log.attachments|length > 0 %}
                    {% set title = 'Прикреплено %d' | format(log.attachments.quantity) %}

                    {% for key, value in log.attachments.name_files %}
                        {% set title = title ~ '\n\r' ~ value ~ ' - ' ~ log.attachments.size_files[key] %}
                    {% endfor %}

                    <i class="fa fa-paperclip" aria-hidden="true" title="{{ title }}"></i>
                {% endif %}
            </td>
            <td>{{ log.sendDatetime|date('d.m.Y H:i:s') }}</td>
            <td>
                <label class="{{ log.sendStatus ? 'label--success' : 'label--danger'}}">
                    <input type="checkbox" {{ log.sendStatus ? 'checked' : ''}} disabled="disabled" />
                    <span></span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td class="center-align"><a href="#log_modal"  data-action="{{ path('log_show', {'id': log.id}) }}" class="get_modal">
                    <i class="far fa-eye" title="Посмотреть подробности"></i>
                </a>
            </td>

        </tr>
    {% else %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7">Нет записей</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Скрипт сортировки :

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

            const getSort = ({ target }) => {
                const order = (target.dataset.order = -(target.dataset.order || -1));
                const index = [...target.parentNode.cells].indexOf(target);
                const collator = new Intl.Collator(['en', 'ru'], { numeric: true });
                const comparator = (index, order) => (a, b) => order * collator.compare(
                    a.children[index].innerHTML,
                    b.children[index].innerHTML
                );

                for(const tBody of target.closest('table').tBodies)
                    tBody.append(...[...tBody.rows].sort(comparator(index, order)));

                for(const cell of target.parentNode.cells)
                    cell.classList.toggle('table', cell === target);
            };

            document.querySelectorAll('.table thead').forEach(tableTH => tableTH.addEventListener('click', () => getSort(event)));


        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После аякс подгрузки вам нужно переинициализировать скрипты для работы, потому что DOM изменился.

можно вынести часть вашего кода в функцию и вызывать уже функцию когда она нужна. Например:

```
function tableSort () {
        const getSort = ({ target }) => {
        const order = (target.dataset.order = -(target.dataset.order || -1));
        const index = [...target.parentNode.cells].indexOf(target);
        const collator = new Intl.Collator(['en', 'ru'], { numeric: true });
        const comparator = (index, order) => (a, b) => order * collator.compare(
            a.children[index].innerHTML,
            b.children[index].innerHTML
        );

        for(const tBody of target.closest('table').tBodies)
            tBody.append(...[...tBody.rows].sort(comparator(index, order)));

        for(const cell of target.parentNode.cells)
            cell.classList.toggle('table', cell === target);
    };

    document.querySelectorAll('.table thead').forEach(tableTH => tableTH.addEventListener('click', () => getSort(event)));
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    tableSort();
});

//после аякса снова вызывайте текущую функцию

tableSort();
```